# File/folder watcher Windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, windows, task-parallel-library

I am developing a C# Windows service that will always watch different folders/files and DB query results on different time intervals. There can be dozens of watchers each watching a specific file or folder or DB query results and sends emails at specific email address if some predefined threshold is met, and begins watching again.

The requirements that I'm trying to address are:

1. Each Watcher must do its task in a separate Thread.
2. If a watcher/tasks throws an exception, it must automatically be restarted after, say, 3 hours.

The strategy I am using:

1. I create a List of `IWatcher` objects which holds many instances of DB, File and Folder watchers

   `IWatcher` is just an interface with some common properties/methods across all DB/File/Folder watchers
2. I call a method `BeginWatch` which creates a separate task for each watcher in watcher's list and stored that task in a `Dictionary`.  The key is set to the ID of watcher.
3. I surrounded thread method's body with try/catch to catch any exception.
4. If an exception occurs, I create a `Timer` object in the `catch()` body, save the watcher's ID (whose work is stopped) in this timer and schedule it with its interval set to a few hours. I remove the task object from tasks' dictionary.
5. Upon occurring of the 'Elapsed' event of this timer, I recreate another task and add it to tasks' dictionary.

Dictionary object for holding tasks against a watcher's ID:

```
private Dictionary<string, TaskDetails> _watcherThreads
```

Here

- `string`: DB/File or Folder watcher's unique ID
- `TaskDetails`: A class that holds a `Task` and other information for that task that I need during  program execution.

**`TaskDetails`:**

```
class TaskDetails
{        
    //The Task object
    public Task WatcherTask { get; set; }

    //CancellationTokenSource reference for each task .. 
    //if we need to cancel tasks individually
    public CancellationTokenSource WatcherCancellationToken { get; set; }

    //It a Timer that will enable this specific task after a few hours 
    //if an exception occurs 
    public MyTimer DisablingTimer { get; set; }

    public TaskDetails(
        Task task, 
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken)
    {
        this.WatcherTask = task;
        this.WatcherCancellationToken = cancellationToken;
    }
}
```

Next I create a list of watchers and then call the following method to create a task for each watcher:

```
public void BeginWatch()
    {
        //this._watchers is the List<IWatcher> where all the watcher objects are stored
        if (this._watchers == null || this._watchers.Count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Watchers' not found");

        //call CreateWatcherThread for each watcher to create a list of threads
        this._watchers.ForEach(CreateWatcherThread);
    }
```

I create a list of tasks with other info:

```
//I call this method and pass in any watcher which i want to run in a new thread
//This method is called savaral times for creating a TASK for each IWatcher object
private void CreateWatcherThread(IWatcher watcher)
{
    IWatcher tmpWatcher = watcher.Copy();
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    //Create a task and run it
    Task _watcherTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => _createWatcherThread(tmpWatcher, cancellationToken),
            cancellationToken.Token, 
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
            TaskScheduler.Default);

    //Add Thread, CancellationToken and IsDisabled = false to dictionary
    //Save Key as WID that will be unique. this will help us retrieving 
    //the right TASK object later from the list 
    this._watcherThreads.Add(
            tmpWatcher.WID,
            new TaskDetails(_watcherTask, cancellationToken)
        );
}
```

Thread method will perform the operation and will set a timer to enable this watcher after some time if an exception occurs.

```
private void _createWatcherThread(IWatcher wat
                                   , CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken)
{   IWatcher watcher = wat.Copy();
    bool hasWatchBegin = false;
    try
    { 
        //run forever
        for (;;)
        {
            //dispose the watcher and stop this thread if CANCEL token has been issued
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {  ((IDisposable)watcher).Dispose();
                break;
            }
            else if (!hasWatchBegin)
            {   watcher.BeginWatch();
                hasWatchBegin = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        //set timer to reactivate this watcher after some hours
        ///This is an extended System.Timers.Timer class. I have only added WatcherID property in it to associate it with a specific Watcher object
        MyTimer enableTaskTimer = new MyTimer();
        enableTaskTimer.Interval 
              = AppSettings.DisabledWatcherDuration; // say 3 hours

        // Store Watcher's ID so we can create another Task later and it begins running this watcher
        enableTaskTimer.WatcherID = watcher.WID;
        enableTaskTimer.Elapsed += DisablingTimer_Elapsed;
        enableTaskTimer.Start();

        //remove the thread from existing list as this task will be recreated again and stored in the list
        this._watcherThreads.Remove(watcher.WID);

        //Log exception
        SingletonLogger.Instance.WriteToLogs(ex.Message, LogSeverity.Error);
    }
}

void DisablingTimer_Elapsed (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{   
    MyTimer timer = sender as MyTimer;

    // get the watcher object by its WID.. MyTime .WatcherID has the Id of the watcher that crashed ... now its time to recreate a task that will again begin a watch
    IWatcher wat = this._watchers.Where(w => w.WID == timer.WatcherID).SingleOrDefault();

    //dispose tie timer ... no more needed
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Dispose();

    //recreate a new thread for watcher
    if(wat != null)
        this.CreateWatcherThread(wat);
}
```

Am I doing this the right way?

Answer (score 2):

Took a quick glance, seems relatively logical. Can't think of anything I would do wildly differently.

I do have one suggestion, though:

Subscribe to the `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event handler. In case you do a mistake or something strange happens with a `Task`, then you can catch that error, log it (stack trace), and keep your service running or restart it or whatever is necessary. If you don't subscribe to that event, your service will simply be closed and you have nothing to help you debug, plus you don't get any notifications.